# Replicating an IRS PDF doc using XSL-FO

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo

I'm trying to replicate a 1098T form from the IRS using XSL-FO. The problem is that since it's a government PDF doc, it needs to be EXACTLY the same. same cell width, height, font-color, font-family, font-size, positioning, dimensions, basically an exact replica.

My question is if there's any tools out there that could help me with this?. This is my first time creating a PDF using XSL-FO. I've done some research and have not yet found anything that could help me with what I need.

[1098T Form Link](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1098t.pdf)

[image]

Comment: RenderX has a tool for importing and drawing on a PDF with data. You would import a blank 1098 then place sample data and export an XSL. That tool is VisualXSL

Comment: Thank you @KevinBrown, I will take look into it :)

Comment: You could use the PDF as the background image of a page of the correct size. With AH Formatter, you could use `background-repeat="paginate"` (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.background-repeat) and have successive pages of the PDF as the background image on successive pages of your document.